# Ctrl+C command is not terminating infinite (while) loop

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have this little script. When I start it and the terminal has the focus <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> stops feh and then the while loop starts feh again. I am expecting that, as long as the terminal(!) has the focus, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> interrupts the while loop and kills feh as well.

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 2
while true; do
feh --cycle-once -zD $1 *.png
done
```

Can someone tell me how I can get that preferred behavior here?

Comment: What's $1 supposed to be ?

Comment: I believe Ctrl+C just kills feh, but not the while loop. You can use Ctrl+Z to stop and then `pkill scriptname`

Comment: Does `SIGQUIT` (CTRL + \\ ) work? If not you need to kill the process using `SIGKILL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#! /bin/bash

sleep 2
while feh --cycle-once -zD $1 *.png; do :; done
```

This way, the cycle will end when feh exits with a nonzero status (as it does when you terminate it).

Comment: `:` is the same as `true`, but there's a typo in the post: there needs to be a space between `do` and `:`.

Answer (score 2):

Trap the INT signal, eg: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

<sub>more infos [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html)</sub>

```
trap trapint 2
function trapint {
    exit 0
}
```

In your code like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap trapint 2
function trapint {
    exit 0
}

sleep 2
while true; do
feh --cycle-once -zD $1 *.png
done
```

Comment: `kill -l 2` shows that signal `2` is the `INT` (`SIGINT`) signal. `kill -l SIGINT` confirms this by showing it is signal `2`. So, `trap trapint 2` is the same as `trap trapint SIGINT`, which is much clearer and easier to read. However, I have found that that doesn't always work. Adding `SIGTERM` with `trap trapint SIGINT SIGTERM` seems to work best. See here: https://serverfault.com/a/160961/357116.